# Angular Typescript Error- error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am getting this error while running my Angular app:

**error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
34                         **{{product.price * quantity.value}}**
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/cart-items/cart-items.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './cart-items.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component CartItemsComponent.**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of productsArrayToPrint">
                        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src={{product.imgaddress}} style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{product.name}}</a></h4>
                                <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success"><strong>{{product.status}}</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                        <input #quantity (keyup)="0" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>{{product.price}}</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>{{product.price * quantity.value}}</strong></td> //ERROR HERE
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
```

If I am changing * to +, then below statement is working

```
<td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>{{product.price + quantity.value}}</strong></td>
```

But I need to use multiplication here.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure quantity.value is a number and not a string?

Comment: quantity is a template reference variable. So quantity.value is a number.

Comment: show us what the `product` and `quantity` types look like. What properties do they have and what do those models look like.

Comment: That definitely has to be because at least one of the values is string. `input` returns string even if you set its `type` as `number`, but angular is able to deal with this kind of stuff using `+`, well angular and javascript/typescript in general . try `{{+product.price * +quantity.value}}`

Comment: @tony Apologies for the confusion. You were right, one if the input was string. Fixed it by changing it to number type. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MishaMashina Apologies for the confusion. You were right, one if the input was string. Fixed it by changing it to number type. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Apologies for the confusion. You were right, one if the input was string. Fixed it by changing it to number type. Thanks for your help.